# Space in the layout even after distributing weight

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

Why there is spaces in the bottom part of the android it was supposed to cover up all the spaces by distributed `weight`

[image]

Comment: post your code and if possible an image of your problem, also you can activate the "Show layout bounds" option from developers options on your phone.

Comment: Add the XML code to Question(not the image of the code) image is good for result

Comment: Post your xml code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an `weightSum` value by using attribute `android:weightSum="value"` to `LinearLayout`.

**Try thise:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="17">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ocean"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="You're Invited"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:background="#009688"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:background="#009688"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Change height of textview to fill_parent

```
android:height="fill_parent"
```